# Sugar CRM CE Blank Screen after installation

Tags: installation, sugarcrm

I have Sugar CE Full 6.5.24 installed on Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64.

After installation I have a blank screen and am unsure what I have done wrong, please assist.

This is the guide I have followed:

http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/7.8/Pro/Installation_and_Upgrade_Guide/#Database

And this one for the dependencies (using PHP 7):

https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-sugarcrm-community-edition-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-vps/

The only known issue I have had is that I was unable to install "jsmin" using pecl but have python-jsmin installed.

I have made a copy of the error log here:

http://46.101.44.70/error.txt

And the installation log here:

http://46.101.44.70/install.txt

Thanks.

Comment: You're using the installation guide for Sugar 7.8 Pro to install Sugar 6.5 CE.  They have very different architecture so I would advise looking for the correct guide.  Sugar CE is also quite old now, so you may have issues using PHP 7.